# Are there any projects to work on the Internet to fight against COVID?

Tags: python

Are there any open source projects that a novice data analyst and mathematician can do, to fight against covid-19 epidemic? I mean, I know that the best I can do is to stay away from people and now I have a laptop and plenty of time to work on some project. But the thing is that I don't know what kind of computations would be useful to save people.

I have Ubuntu, LibreOffice, R, Python, and Sagemath installed on my computer.

Comment: I am working on https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid but it is not coded in Python (but mostly in C++) even if we have some Python scripts. And not yet using data science techniques (except databases)

Comment: The simplest way is [foldingathome.org](https://foldingathome.org/)

Answer (score 8):

You might want to have a look at this [Kaggle initiative](https://www.kaggle.com/covid19) and this github [repository with South Korea data](https://github.com/GermanCM/Data-Science-for-COVID-19)

Answer (score 4):

I think there are three very different kinds of contributions that can be made:

- Professional: many countries and organizations (typically [the EU](https://ec.europa.eu/info/news/coronavirus-eu-mobilises-eur10-million-for-research-2020-jan-31_en), also many NGOs) have issued emergency calls for proposals, some of them involve data science research either about the disease itself or for dealing with its consequences. Participating to these projects usually requires a team of researchers but conditions vary.
- Citizen Science: participating to a research project as a non-professional, usually through a platform such as [SciStarter](https://scistarter.org/) or [Zooniverse](https://www.zooniverse.org/). Some of these projects are in the medical domain but I haven't seen any specifically related to the coronavirus yet.
- Doing your own project and publishing the results. There are many datasets available (see e.g. [this question on OpenDataSE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16185/covid19-coronavirus-case-data-count-of-cases-and-deaths)).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of projects to fight Covid-19, [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/26/ways-to-help-the-fight-against-covid-19-from-home/).